# Сериализация, преобразование объекта в формат JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

Сериализация — это преобразование объекта в формат JSON. 
класс

```
class Person {
 int id;
 String name;
 int age;
 Person(this.id, this.name, this. age);
}
```

объект

```
//объект
 _person = Person(1, "Ivan", 36);
```

формат JSON

```
{
 "id" : 1,
 "name" : "Ivan",
 "age" : 36
}
```

Я хочу сделать сериализацию, преобразовать объект в формат JSON и вывести его на экран. У меня этоне получается. Почему? Далее полный код и скриншот ошибки.
***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 Person _person;
 String _str = '';

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  //объект
  _person = Person(1, "Ivan", 36);
  //сериализация, преобразование объекта в формат JSON
  _str = jsonEncode(_person);

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: [
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
     child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: Text(
       _str
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}

class Person {
 int id;
 String name;
 int age;
 Person(this.id, this.name, this. age);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В языке GO, это решается приблизительно так
***main.go***

```
package main

import (
 "encoding/json"
 "net/http"
)

func main() {
 http.HandleFunc("/", myController1)
 http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil)
}

type Number struct {
 Id int64 `json:"id"` // свойство Id будет преобразовано в ключ "id"
 Num int64 `json:"num"` // свойство Num будет преобразовано в ключ "num"
 En string `json:"en"` // свойство En будет преобразовано в ключ "en"
 Ru string `json:"ru"` // свойство Ru будет преобразовано в ключ "ru"
}

func myController1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

 n0 := Number {
  Id: 0,
  Num: 0,
  En: "zero",
  Ru: "ноль",
 }

 encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
 err := encoder.Encode(&n0)
 if err != nil {
  panic(err)
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавте в сериализуемый класс метод `toJson`:

```dart
class Person {
  int id;
  String name;
  int age;
  Person(this.id, this.name, this. age);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
    {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'age': age,
    };
}
```

[Здесь](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes) подробно всё расписано.

Comment: Уважаемый Spatz, огромное Вам спасибо!